# Which virtualization software supports 3D acceleration?

Tags: server, virtualization, 3d

I want to run a virtualisation server on my notebook.

When ever I log onto my notebook I want to be able to initialise a virtual machine and work with it.

The virtual machine could be located off of the notebook on a removable hard disk drive or web ftp etc.

I would like 3D support on my virtual instances as I still want to be able to play StarCraft 2 on a Windows 7 virtual machine.

Is there software out there that allows for all of this?

I know of software which supports 3D and I know of virtualisation server software but I want both in one.

Does it exist or is it possible to do so but maybe not as elegantly as I have described?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose for a VMware product - Player, Server, Workstation.

Tutorial [for 3D acceleration in virtual machines](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualization-3d-support-vmware.html)

Keep me informed

Comment: thanks for the info. I will try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Ilias,  I followed the instructions using Windows 7 as the host and ran Windows XP SP 3 as the guest.  I then ran Neverball and it all worked... quite impressed.  I am going to try StarCraft 2 now, but I think the 3D requirements may not be met.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: Tested StarCraft 2 on the win xp sp 3 VMWare VM... And it worked remarkablely well. FPS was between 25 and 35, with all settings set to low. Not the best for competitive play. Quite impressed.

Answer (score 3):

Vmware player supports 3d acceleration , as does virtualbox.

However, playing starcraft under virtualised windows machine would give poor performance.

A better solution would be to use wine (Open Source Software for running Windows applications on other operating systems) to run starcraft on linux without requiring virtualisation. 
see this blog post (but also read the comments - some people say it works on a wine install without any tweaking!)

http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.com/2010/07/howto-starcraft-2-on-linux-with-wine.html

the wine appdb gives starcraft II a platinum status on ubuntu:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882&iTestingId=60579

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have been running StarCraft 2 on my ubuntu 10.10 installation. was a bloody mission to get going but  got it working.  Mostly because I am not very skilled with Linux/Unix...  I am looking for a solution that removes operating system dependencies on my notebook.  So I can change from OS to OS as I see fit.  Example would be to setup the perfect windows 7 environment for me to write .net apps... then be able to flip over to Ubuntu, for arguments sake, and start using that environment for some other development.  But currently I still want to be able to play StarCraft 2 :)